# Состояние ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, браузер

Доброй ночи.
При выполнении аякс запроса результат возвращается та текущую страницу в div блок. Предыдущее значение этого блока удаляется.

```
function listdir(){
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('POST', 'App.php', true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhttp.send("folder="+document.getElementById('folder').value);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
            var temp = "folder="+document.getElementById('folder').value;
            history.pushState("folder="+document.getElementById('folder').value, '', 'items');
            console.log(xhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

Необходимо записать в историю браузера предыдущее состояние страницы. Что-бы при клике назад вывелась предыдущая страница.

```
history.pushState("folder="+document.getElementById('folder').value, '', 'items');
```

Не могу понять какой объект состояние передаётся при запросе типа post.

Comment: попробуй через localStorage

Comment: Всё равно не понимаю как это сделать, js не глубоко знаю.

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) можно прочесть про localStorage.